# Storing Client and Server Data in iOS app

Tags: ios, json, nsuserdefaults

I have an iOS app.

It's primary function is to show the user information.

If it has internet connection. Request and Store a JSON string from a server. 
Else. Store a client side version of this data.

What would be the best approach to incorporate this into an app. Would it be to share NSUserDefaults for both sets of information, overwriting if the app has internet connection or not?

And what about if device only has mobile data. Do I incorporate time-outs?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details. If you don't have an Internet connection, where does the data come from? Does it change? Where does it change?

Comment: I store a local copy of the json string client side

Comment: Of the same thing that I retrieve from the server. But the server data changes

Comment: How are you getting the same data that you retrieve from the server if you can't access the server? What is the data? What's the origin? Does it change? Where does it change? We need more details.

Comment: Its just an example of the default data... It doesnt matter as I decode it the same way...

Answer (score 0):

You can have files as mobile data in main bundle, and a file named Version to save the version of the files,when first launch your app ,save them in sandBox .when lanuch app ,you request web services for a JSON ,describ the version of the files,when the version of a file is different,update the file in sandBox.